# Existe forma mais eficiente de criar um array a partir de outro array dinamicamente, filtrando o conteúdo do primeiro?

Tags: python, array, numpy, python-2.7

Tenho um array de valores que podem incluir vários numpy.nan:

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array ( [1, 2, np.nan, 4] )
```

E quero iterar sobre seus itens para criar um novo array sem os np.nan.

A forma que eu conheço para criar arrays dinamicamente é criar um array de zeros (`np.zeros()`) e preenchê-lo com conteúdo de interesse *a posteriori*.

Da forma como faço, tenho que iterar o array `a` duas vezes: uma pra contar quantos `np.nan`s eu vou encontrar e reduzir esse número da dimensão do array `b`; e a segunda iteração para popular o array `b`:

```py
# Contando quantos nan's
count = 0
for e in a:
if np.isnan(e):
    count += 1

# criando o array vazio do tamanho certo
size = a.shape[0]
b = np.zeros( (size - count, ) )

# populando o array com o conteúdo pertinente
ind = 0
for e in a:
    if not np.isnan(e):
        b[ind] = e
        ind += 1
```

Imagino que também seja possível fazer isso convertendo `a` pra lista (já que é unidimensional) e filtrar essa lista para a lista `b` convertendo-a em seguida pra array.

Mas existe uma forma mais eficiente de se fazer isso apenas com arrays?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Você pode filtrar os valores usando uma expressão no índice:

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array ( [1, 2, np.nan, 4] )

# Filtra NaN
filtrado = a[~np.isnan(a)]
```

A expressão `np.isnan(a)` retorna um vetor de booleanos indicando, para cada posição do array `a`, se ele é ou não `NaN`. O `~` nega esse vetor. Então você usa o mecanismo de [indexação booleana](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) para selecionar apenas os registros cujo valor de `~np.isnan(a)` seja `True`.

Comment: Uma alternativa seria `filter(lambda n: ~np.isnan(n), a)`, mas creio que a indexação booleana sugerida pelo @rodrigorgs seja mais eficiente. :)

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que a solução padrão para o seu problema é utilizar a função `filter` cuja sintaxe é:

```
filter(função_booleana, valor_interavel)
```

Para cada valor em `valor_interavel`, a função executa `função_booleana` com o valor, filtrado-o do resultado caso a função_booleana retorne falso.
Você pode utilizar em conjunto com `isnan` assim:

```
filter(np.isnan, seu_array)
```

O melhor de tudo é que a solução fica compacta e clara. Note que você não precisa importar nenhum módulo para obter a função filter, já que ela é implementada pelo interpretador Python.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o **set** do python ele remove os itens repetido de uma lista.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = a + [4,5,6,3,2,1]
>>> print b
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 2, 1]
>>> print set(b)
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Acho que isso resolve seu problema!

Comment: na realidade não resolve. Eu quero remover os itens da lista A a partir do conteudo da lista B, não fazer uma lista só. A resposta aceita realmente atende à pergunta. Obrigado, de qualquer forma. ;)